# Under "How To Ask" .. Rename "Is your question about" to "Questions here should be about"

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, wording, tips

For example "Is your question about computer software or computer hardware?" on SU. How am I supposed to answer that question? There is no button. :P

It may seem strange but when I was new and I first read on the right of this Meta site I read "Is your question about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network?"

I got lost.. what is that supposed to mean? I thought it meant that the StackExchange engine was off topic and belonged on another site...