# Make a new meta tag "tweak" that can be used instead of feature-request or bug

Tags: discussion, tags, required-tags

> **Example question:** [Under "How To Ask" .. Rename "Is your question about" to "Questions here should be about"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77314/under-how-to-ask-rename-is-your-question-about-to-questions-here-should-b)

That is not really a new feature,, nor is it a bug. It is definitely a tweak. Maybe not a minor tweak if every site has to be changed,, but it is not a new feature or a bug.

Comment: *Resists the urge to tag this question as tweak*

Comment: No doubt ! Of course it probably is a tweak,, but come to think of it.. it is really a discussion so far :) @BenV

Answer (score 2):

There are usually two cases:

1. It's a feature request if the functionality works okay, but could be better.
2. It's a bug if the functionality is incorrect, or is misleading.

Classifying these types of requests as either a feature request or a bug is close enough. Besides, where do we draw the line between a tweak and a feature or a bug?

On Meta, most of the time at least, the importance of a request is proportional to the number of votes on the question. So this functionality is pretty much built in already.